# Select row when cell in tableview is a tableview iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In my app, I am using tableview and cell in this which is tableview too. All things work good but when I want to handler selected cell on tableview which is a cell but i don't control

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

This function call at tableview parent only. But in my case, i want to call this function in both of tableview (parent tableview and tableview in cell).

Thanks!

Comment: having a table view inside another table view cell doesn't make a lot of sense... try working with sections and use only one instance of `UITableView`, then you won't have to deal with this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported UITableViewDelegate? and add it to you table view as self.tableView.delegate = self,Better to check once!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the table view of the cell, please set the delegate and datasource as the cell views reference.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, your parent tableView get the select action and block the child table view from receive this action. I think there're two or more approaches to resolve this:
 1. Change your view hierachy (contruct) of your view (don't make detail table view as a cell of the parent table). Make the detail table view as top view, so it could received select action, then maybe, pass this action to (parent) tableview.
 2. Add UIGestureRecognizer to both child tableView and parent tableView, then check to perform tap action to both of them

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
   shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```